# In IntelliJ, is there a shortcut to get variable I've already typed to be a parameter in a method I want to type?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose I have this code:

```
var x = 2;
var y = x;
```

Then I realize that I actually wanted this:

```
var y = someMethod(x);
```

To accomplish this, first I need to position the cursor to the left of "x", then type "someMethod(", then move my cursor to the right, and then add the final ")".

What I'd love is to have a way to, say, highlight "x", and have it automatically get inserted as a parameter to whatever I start typing.

Is there something for this in IntelliJ?

Comment: So, you want a method that will *”move my cursor to the right, and then add the final”*, which returns the value of “x” which is can then be passed to your other method

Comment: @MadProgrammer no, I don't want a method. I want a way to do this with IntelliJ.

Comment: So you want something like a "auto complete hint"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Statement Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#statements_completion):

- Point the cursor before `x`
- Start typing the method name
- Select the needed variant and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor at the left of `x`, start typing the method name and wait for the autocompletion sugestions to appear (if they don't press CTRL+Space), find your method in the list, select it with keyboard arrows, and press CTR+SHIFT+ENTER. IDEA will automatically use `x` as the parameter of the method.

Comment: This doesn't work. Maybe because I'm on the community edition?

Comment: No, sorry, my mistake, I forgot to add CTRL+SHIFT to the ENTER. I've just updated it.