# In Pycharm, is there a shortcut to get variable I've already typed to be a parameter in a method I want to type?

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

[You can do this in Intellij with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483076/in-intellij-is-there-a-shortcut-to-get-variable-ive-already-typed-to-be-a-para). I thought since Pycharm is made by the same company and it has a lot of the same functionalities it would work the same but it doesn't.

if I have:

x = 1

y = x

and I put my cursor to the left of x and type math.sqrt, select the function and press ctrl+shift+enter i get:

x = 1

y = math.sqrt()x

instead of:

x = 1

y = math.sqrt(x)

Comment: I had Ctrl + Shift + Enter linked to exactly the same commands in my two keymaps, but the shortcut never results in `math.sqrt(x)` being autocompleted. That said, this is probably a discrepancy between the two IDEs.